# A No-linear differential equation

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-conditions

I'm recently figuring out how to make this equation solved but Mathematica does not solve this??!!

DSolve[{ y'[t]== ((3 a)/2 (y[t] - b/(2 a))^2 + k ((3 a)/2 - 1) t^-2 - ((a f)/2 + (3 b^2)/(8 a)))/(t  y[t] ), y[1] == y0}, y, t]

a,b, k and f  are the positive parameters.

Thank guys

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I changed it in Inputform to see better.

Comment: It's still not formatted right — at least before, it could be copied and pasted directly into *Mathematica*. But now it's a different equation than at first.

Comment: It can be solved for `b = 0`, but probably not for other values.  Any reason to think it can be solved symbolically?

Comment: for b=0 it gets easy but I have to consider b.

Comment: Can I solve this for singularities as well?

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to have a closed form analytical solution. The next best thing (other than a numerical solution) is to find a series solution by expanding around $t=1$

```
ClearAll[y, t, a, b, k, f]
ode = t*y[t]*y'[t] + (3*a)/2*(y[t] - b/(2*a))^2 + 
    k*((3*a)/2 - 1)*t^(-2) - ((a*f)/2 + (3*b^2)/(8*a)) == 0;
AsymptoticDSolveValue[{ode, y[1] == y0}, y[t], {t, 1, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's a very good idea, also I was thinking about how we can plot this on the surface (2D) to see if there are some singularities?!!

Comment: I would like to plot this like that:

Comment: @Mathecis to plot the above solution, just need to define numerical values for all the unknown parameters, `y0,a,b,k,f` and after that you can use the plot command on the result.

Comment: Is no any method to see an analytical way??

Comment: @Mathecis I do not think there is no closed form solution. series method is the next best thing. But you can ask at the math forum if you want.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Nasser (ناصر)